# Infinite Viewpager image slider from both sides

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

I wanted to make a Viewpager image slider in a Pager Adapter which is swipeable from both sides (right to left) and (left to right).
The code below can only start from the first position and move to the right but i want it to go both ways ,that is from left to right and right to left from any position.

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.cake, R.drawable.cake1, R.drawable.cake2};


public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

}

@Override


public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

 private int pos = 0;


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_slide, null);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    imageView.setImageResource(images[pos%images.length]);
    imageView.setPaddingRelative(15, 0, 15, 0);
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(view, 0);


    if (pos >= images.length - 1)
        pos = 0;
    else
        pos++;


    return view;


}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;

    vp.removeView(view);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[you will find your solution on this link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Comment: But this implementation is more complicated. I have used a viewpager for the image slides and can only move one way from right to left. My desired output is to be able to swipe from left to right also from the first position. An example of it is on the homepage of the flipkart app . An image slider that is infinite from both ways. Btw thanks for your reply.